# SQL Server race condition issue with range lock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, deadlock

I'm implementing a queue in SQL Server (please no discussions about this)  and am running into a race condition issue. The T-SQL of interest is the following:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable
begin tran
declare @RecordId int
declare @CurrentTS datetime2
set @CurrentTS=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
select top 1 @RecordId=Id from QueuedImportJobs with (updlock) where Status=@Status and (LeaseTimeout is null or @CurrentTS>LeaseTimeout) order by Id asc
if @@ROWCOUNT> 0
begin
update QueuedImportJobs set LeaseTimeout = DATEADD(mi,5,@CurrentTS), LeaseTicket=newid() where Id=@RecordId
select * from QueuedImportJobs where Id = @RecordId
end
commit tran
```

`RecordId` is the PK and there is also an index on `Status,LeaseTimeout`.

What I'm basically doing is select a record of which the lease happens to be expired, while simultaneously updating the lease time with 5 minutes and setting a new lease ticket.

So the problem is that I'm getting deadlocks when I run this code in parallel using a couple of threads. I've debugged it up to the point where I found out that the update statement sometimes gets executing twice for the same record. Now, I was under the impression that the `with (updlock)` should prevent this (it also happens with `xlock` btw, not with `tablockx`). So it actually look like there is a RangeS-U and a RangeX-X lock on the same range of records, which ought to be impossible.

So what am I missing? I'm thinking it might have something to do with the top 1 clause or that SQL Server does not know that `where Id=@RecordId` is actually in the locked range?

Deadlock graph:
[image]

Table schema (simplified):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the locks are on different HOBT's.  Are there multiple indexes on the table?

If so, the select `with (updlock)` might only take an `update` lock on one index.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 indexes. Can you hint at using both indexes? I'm not that familiar with HOBT's, so maybe you can enlighten me :)

Comment: A hobt is a table without indexes (heap) or a binary tree (index).  You can't hint at locking multiple indexes.  AaronBertrand's answer should help, we use something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Id INT);

UPDATE TOP (1) dbo.QueuedImportJobs 
  SET LeaseTimeout = DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @t
  WHERE Status = @Status 
  AND COALESCE(LeaseTimeout, '19000101') < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.QueuedImportJobs 
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @t);
```

As an aside you might want to have `ORDER BY` to ensure the selected row is the first one on the queue according to the desired index order. If the index on Id is clustered, this is probably how it will work anyway, but there is no guarantee unless you say so. This will require a slight re-structuring of the query, since you can't apply `ORDER BY` (or an index hint) directly on an `UPDATE`, e.g.:

```
WITH x AS
(
  SELECT TOP (1) Id, LeaseTimeout
    FROM dbo.QueuedImportJobs
    WHERE Status = @Status 
    AND COALESCE(LeaseTimeout, '19000101') < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY Id
)
UPDATE x
  SET LeaseTimeout = DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @t;
```

Comment: With this query, how would the OP retrieve the claimed job's details?  An output clause might help

Comment: This might actually work, I'll check it out tomorrow. Still wonder why my solution doesn't work though.

Comment: @Freek I think Andomar is right, you're deadlocking on two different indexes, which probably isn't obvious given you've provided a simplified version of your schema. But I have solved many deadlock problems for clients in the past by reducing their `SELECT ... if rows then do stuff ... UPDATE/DELETE` to a much more simple, direct, single atomic action.